# How to avoid all popups opening up on button press in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-props

I am working on a react app using redux.Now I have a table with each table row having a edit button that opens a popup.I have set one boolean flag in redux store that toggles from `openeditpopup:true` and `openeditpopup:false`.Now What issue i am facing is,on pressing `edit` button of 1 table row,popups of all the rows open and I am confused how to rectify this issue.

Here's my code:

```
         <Grid.Row>
              <Grid.Column width={1} />
              <Grid.Column width={14}>
                
              { 
              this.props.openeditpopup ? <EditPopUp position='bottom-right'/> : 
               <div></div>}

              </Grid.Column>
         
              <Grid.Column width={1} />
            </Grid.Row>
```

In the above code I am checking whether the `openeditpopup` flag is true and false and showing the popup when true.

`EditPopup`

```
class PopUp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.triggerState = this.triggerState.bind(this);
  }

  triggerState() {
    if (this.props.open) {
      this.props.closeEditPopup();
    } else {
      this.props.openEditPopup();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const trigger = (<Typography size='small' className='inline' onClick={this.triggerState} customLink>{this.props.triggertext}</Typography>);

    return (
      <CommonPopup
        trigger={trigger}
        open={this.props.open}
        style={{ width: this.props.width, zIndex: '500' }}
        flowing
        position={this.props.position}
        onClickClose={false}
        popupActions={<PopupActions triggerState={this.triggerState} />}
      >
        <Grid.Row style={{maxHeight: '300px', minHeight: '300px', overflow: 'scroll' }}>
          <Grid.Column>
            <FormLayout />
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid.Row>
      </CommonPopup>
    );
  }
}
```

`CommonPopup`

```
  render() {
    const {
      trigger,id, label, children, position, on, offset, style, popupActions, hideOnScroll, HeaderRenderer, FooterRenderer, ...other
    } = this.props;

      position.replace(/left/g, 'oldLeft').replace(/right/g, 'left').replace(/oldLeft/g, 'right');
    

    console.log(id)
    return (
      <Popup
      key={id}  
      trigger={trigger}
        on={on}
        style={style}
        // offset={offset}
        position={position}
        open={this.state.open}
        onClose={this.onClose}
        onOpen={this.onOpen}
        onMount={this.onMount}
        onUnmount={this.onUnmount}
        hideOnScroll={hideOnScroll}
        content={(
          <Grid>
            {<HeaderRenderer {...this.props} popupClose={this.onClose} />}
            {children}
            <Divider fitted />
            {<FooterRenderer {...this.props} popupClose={this.onClose} />}
          </Grid>
)}
        {...other}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: for each row having edit button, have you given unique key to them? like <td key='@123'></td>

Comment: no,i havent given em a key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply handle a situation like this by declaring the `EditPopUp` component once (this means you have to declare `EditPopUp` for all rows only once) & pass necessary props to that component if you need to customize anything.

```js
<>
  <Grid.Row>
    <Grid.Column width={1} />
    <Grid.Column width={1} />
  </Grid.Row>

  <Grid.Row>
    <Grid.Column width={1} />
    <Grid.Column width={1} />
  </Grid.Row>

  <Grid.Row>
    <Grid.Column width={1} />
    <Grid.Column width={1} />
  </Grid.Row>

  // Popup with props
  {this.props.openeditpopup ? (
    <EditPopUp position="bottom-right" rowID={this.props.rowID} />
  ) : (
    <div></div>
  )}
</>
```

Comment: even after assigning different keys,its not working

Comment: it still opens all the popups

Comment: I'm proposing a different solution. Try that @rudeTool

Comment: in the ui,in right upper corner,click on add new client then add a name,select a access grants then status and save.add 2 clients like this.then when you press edit button in the table,it renders both the popup

Comment: updated link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-star-gw5rh

Comment: @rudeTool, your implementation was wrong. I have updated yours simply by creating another function to return popUp structure & include that after the table. Now appear only one popup. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/popup-render-68388093-z6lu6?file=/src/clientDashboard/Table/InfiniteTable.jsx:6151-6626)

Comment: thank you,but how can I place that popup just below edit button.just like its for add client button?

Comment: [This is how normally popup appears on web pages.](https://d3ds0r8ijvk7u6.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2016/08/31111247/screenshot-zapier.com-2016-08-29-11-08-33.png) You can update styles as you like. My answer is to solve your original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <Grid.Row>
       <Grid.Column width={1} />
       <Grid.Column width={14}>
                
       { this.props.openeditpopup && <EditPopUp position='bottom-right' rowID={this.props.rowID} /> }

       </Grid.Column>
         
       <Grid.Column width={1} />
    </Grid.Row>
```

Comment: I will update my EditPopup component in the ques